# Type checking when code is running

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am using TypeScript on Node.js. TypeScript checks types during compilation, but JavaScript code after compiling is not checking types. For example, this code throws an error:

```
var test : number;
test = 'test';
```

But this code on Express will work normally:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var test : number;
    test = req.body.test;
    res.end(req.body.test);
});
```

As a result, I have `test` with string type, although `test` was a number. 
How can I avoid this problem? How do I check the type of variables when code is running?

Comment: The point of TypeScript is _static_ type checking, not runtime type checking

Comment: Are there any tools for runtime type checking on JavaScript?

Comment: `if (typeof test === 'string') ... else throw new TypeError(...)`

Comment: https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=runtime%20type%20checking%20javascript

Comment: Use https://github.com/typings/typings to make typescript typecheck express code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I check the type of variables when code is running

Basically TypeScript is *inferring* the type of `req` to be `any`. This means it it as *completely* not type checked to a large extent.

You can disable this with `noImplicitAny` option and then TypeScript will flag errors when it cannot determine the *type* of a variable. That would make your code sample a *compile time* error.